# What to do when employees are dissatisfied with the salary, however there is no possibility to increase it?

Tags: salary, human-resources, job-satisfaction

I work as a consultant, and conduct an organizational climate measurement for a client company. What I found is that the workers are not satisfied with their wages (which is understandable since most of them receive the minimum wage).

The problem is that the CEO is not willing to make salary improvements.

So what would be the best way to approach this problem from a human resources perspective?

The most logical thing would be to work on issues related to emotional salary, but I would like to hear other opinions.

Comment: "How can I pay at the grocery store without using any form of money?"

Comment: "So what would be the best way to approach this problem from a human resources perspective?" Hire 14 year-olds and replace them with new 14 year-olds every year. Automate. Outsource the work to your own customers.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I think that should probably be an Answer.

Comment: Has any minimum wage employee ever been "satisfied" with their wages?

Comment: I'm sure these downvotes are simply because you're on the side of the employer here (the general attitude on TWP is that all employers and managers are evil :p), but this question also doesn't state what your desired outcome is. ①Include your desired outcome. ②At least pretend not to be on the CEO's side in this question

Comment: The real question is why the resignations have not yet started; once that avalanche gains momentum, there will be no stopping it. And the best always leave first, as they are more able to find something else.

Comment: You made climate measurment. You conclude it's bad due to low wages. The option is to make CEO aware that personell will be doing bare minimum (if not less), there will be heavy rotation and there could be problems with hiring new people.

Comment: @Mars The employer here literally wants to pay as little as they can without breaking the law. I appreciate that boot polish is tasty and those vulnerable CEOs need you to defend them from us but at least acknowledge that the downvotes are justified.

Comment: @Studoku It's worth remembering that downvotes are meant for badly structured questions. Just because OP is a bootlicker doesn't mean that the question doesn't deserve an answer... it just deserves a good "Deal with the consequences of poor worker motivation and high turnover" answer.

Comment: @Studoku What justified the downvotes? As Adonalsium states, downvotes are for badly written questions. I have seen much worse than this (which is too broad) get much better scores, leading me to believe that it's merely because OP is a bootlicker. That's just not what downvotes are for

Comment: To clarify 1) I am an external consultant, i.e. I am not part of the company 2) Obviously I tried  to get Ceo to increase salaries, however the company did not give up on this due to financial issues 3) Therefore I have two options: Tell the CEO: "Ok is your problem if you don't want to raise salaries, manage the consequences" or try to give employees access to other benefits because the company doesn't want to raise salaries. I prefer the last one, I guess I'm a bad human being and a bootlicker because of that XD

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> What I found is that the workers are not satisfied with their wages

Is this ever not found in a company? Who does not think they should get a raise?

> So what would be the best way to approach this problem from a human resources perspective? The most logical thing would be to work on issues related to emotional salary, but I would like to hear other opinions.

Emotional salary works when the trade off is being happier at work instead of buying a new boat. The challenge with minimum wage is that for many, it is a survival wage, so having a nice Christmas card isn't a motivator.

You do not state your industry, but figure out what types of people end up working at the particular company. Are they young single uneducated men? Single moms with children? Seniors looking for something to do? Felons stuck in the job? Students at the local university?

There are lots of low-cost perks which could be offered. Moms could be given more flexibility. Seniors could be offered chairs if they are at the cash register. Felons could be offered easy access to a reference or flexibility to see their parole officers (this is an actual problem for many of them who work regular hours as often they must check in during regular hours). Students could be given scholarship lists.

Figure out why your workers work there and find a perk which benefits them.

Comment: It might be also an option to just *ask* your employees what they want. The top answer will of course be a better salary, but ask for a top 3 of answers. If you get "salary, salary, and did I already mention salary" in response, you might want to investigate why your employees are even working for you. If not, look at the #2 and #3 answers.

Answer (score 20):

- Hire 14 year-olds and replace them with new 14 year-olds every year. (examples: McDonalds, Girl Scouts)
- Automate.
- Tell them they're contractors now, but that they'll make serious cash recruiting others. (examples: Avon, Tupperware, Uber)
- Outsource the work, or part of the work, to your own customers (examples: Ikea, Waze, Hot Pot City, StackOverflow)

Comment: Brilliant answer - but you forgot two points: 5.) Move your main-office to a developing country where the minimum wage is the lowest world-wide and there are no unions or employment laws so you can squeeze 80h/week out of your underaged workers. 6.) Pay them in food coupons that they can trade in only at your own overpriced store.. ;)

Comment: @iLuvLogix Or maybe I didn't forget anything but I just didn't want to be too helpful, because there is always a tiny chance that one of my draconian suggestions gets implemented.

Comment: Hello, My name is Tennessee Ford and I think I have your company anthem :)

Comment: Hiring potential migrants from overseas using an employment-based visa, then oppressing them is also a favorite

Answer (score 8):

This is clearly an issue with the wages. Minimum wages means CEO is trying to get away with as little wages s/he can give.

This is not your problem to handle. Report the feedback from employees to the CEO, without throwing any of them under the bus. Its the CEO's decision to make. It's affecting morale and soon people will start to leave and you will be left with mediocre staff that are stuck because they cannot get a better job.

Answer (score 1):

-One possibility is to outsource the departement to a country with lower minimum wages.

- also, if legal, one can allow the workers to do more paid work, so they can get a living wage by working more hours
- tax free benefits (if legal) like a transportation subscription might be win-win
- subsidised food in the canteen

Also the notion that increase is impossible has to be tested. Does the competition pay more?